# How to Store PayPal Subscription ID in MongoDB After Payment?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, paypal

I'm working on integrating PayPal subscriptions into my Node.js application and need to store the subscription ID in a MongoDB database after a successful payment. Despite following the PayPal subscription creation and execution process, the `subscriptionId` isn't being saved as expected. I'm looking for guidance on how to ensure the `subscriptionId` is correctly stored in MongoDB.

**Back-end's Code:**

***middlewares/auth.js***

***models/user.js***

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    subscriptionId: { 
        type: String,
        required: false, 
        unique: true,  
    },
});

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
module.exports = User;
```

***routes/paypal.js***

```js
paypalRouter.post("/create-subscription", async (req,res) => {
  try {
    const subscriptionDetails = {
      plan_id: process.env.PAYPAL_SANDBOX_BUSSINESS_SUBSCRIPTION_PLAN_ID,
     
      application_context: {
        brand_name: "pomoworko.com",
        return_url: "http://localhost:3001/paypal/execute-subscription",
        cancel_url: "http://localhost:3001/paypal/cancel-subscription",
      }
    };

    // Generar un token de acceso
    const params = new URLSearchParams();
    params.append("grant_type", "client_credentials");
    const authResponse = await axios.post(
      "https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token",
      params,
      {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        },
        auth: {
          username: process.env.PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID,
          password: process.env.PAYPAL_SECRET,
        },
      }
    );

    const access_token = authResponse.data.access_token;

    // Crear la suscripción
    const response = await axios.post(
      "https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/billing/subscriptions",
      subscriptionDetails,
      {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${access_token}`,
        },
      }
    );

    console.log(response.data);
    // Aquí devolvemos el ID de la suscripción en la respuesta
    console.error();
    return res.json({ subscriptionId: response.data.id, ...response.data });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return res.status(500).json("Something goes wrong");
  }
});



paypalRouter.get("/execute-subscription", async (req, res) => {
  const { token } = req.query; // El token de la suscripción que PayPal envía de vuelta

  try {
    // Paso 1: Obtener el Token de Acceso
    const params = new URLSearchParams();
    params.append("grant_type", "client_credentials");
    const authResponse = await axios.post("https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token", params, {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      },
      auth: {
        username: process.env.PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID,
        password: process.env.PAYPAL_SECRET,
      },
    });

    const access_token = authResponse.data.access_token;

    // Paso 2: Confirmar la Suscripción
    // Nota: Debes reemplazar {subscription_id} con el ID de suscripción real obtenido previamente o pasado a través de la URL si es posible.
    const subscriptionId = authResponse.data.id; // Necesitas obtener este ID de alguna manera, generalmente se guarda en la base de datos antes de redirigir al usuario a PayPal
    const executeResponse = 
    await axios.post(`https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/billing/subscriptions/${subscriptionId}/activate`, {}, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${access_token}`,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
    });

    console.log("Subscription confirmed:", executeResponse.data);
    console.error();
        res.send("Subscription successful!");
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error executing subscription:", error.response ? error.response.data : error.message);
    res.status(500).send("An error occurred while executing the subscription.");
  }
});
```

After executing the subscription, I expect to find the `subscriptionId` stored in the user's document in MongoDB, but it appears to be missing. There are no errors thrown by MongoDB or in my Node.js server logs.

Has anyone faced a similar issue or can offer insights into what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Too much code really, you should be able to instrument and debug it yourself and narrow down the problem to a more specific question